# stellar core frozen at ledger 1187897

Tags: stellar-core

I have a problem with two stellar-core installations that were installed by the stellar quickstart image (https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/). I have two running testnet-instances of it at different hosters, started more than a month apart.
The earlier one froze after some time of working so I just restarted it. Some time afterwards I deployed the second node.
Both worked fine for some time but now both stellar-core instances are frozen at the same ledger 1187897. 
Again, they run on different hosters/environments so I have no clue what happened here. Can anyone relate?

This is as much data as I could obtain. Note that the configs only slightly differ in their "CATCHUP_RECENT" setting.
I am unable to find any logfile, maybe this is related to `LOG_FILE_PATH=""`. Stdout is logged but does not contain any useful messages at all (no stellar-core output).

### Instance 1 data

- cat /opt/stellar/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-testnet1.stellar.org",
"core-testnet2.stellar.org",
"core-testnet3.stellar.org"]

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=XXX user=XXX password=XXX"
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1
CATCHUP_RECENT=208640

#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51 # rounded up -> 2 nodes out of 3
VALIDATORS=[
"GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
"GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
"GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]

[HISTORY.cache]
get="cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}"

#The history store of the Stellar testnet
[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

- stellar-core http-command 'info'

```
2019-10-24T08:12:52.307 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:12:52.312 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1208
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:12:52.320 GAVEF [default INFO] {
   "info" : {
      "build" : "v11.3.0rc1",
      "history_failure_rate" : "0.25",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 835969,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 5000000,
         "closeTime" : 1571068803,
         "hash" : "e70b405e62cf125668422aa7a59bfcfc2910cfbba7d1eda9e1755567ba95712d",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 1187897,
         "version" : 11
      },
      "network" : "Test SDF Network ; September 2015",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 8,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 11,
      "quorum" : {
         "node" : "GD65K",
         "qset" : {
            "agree" : 3,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 2,
            "hash" : "59d361",
            "ledger" : 1341320,
            "missing" : 0,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
         },
         "transitive" : {
            "critical" : null,
            "intersection" : true,
            "last_check_ledger" : 1329406,
            "node_count" : 4
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2019-10-23T14:05:53Z",
      "state" : "Catching up",
      "status" : [ "Catching up: Running: catchup" ]
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'peers'

```
2019-10-24T08:24:40.910 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:24:40.914 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1732
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:24:40.920 GAGNI [default INFO] {
   "authenticated_peers" : {
      "inbound" : null,
      "outbound" : [
         {
            "address" : "13.114.104.43:11625",
            "id" : "GAEPM",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.1.0 (324c1bd61b0e9bada63e0d696d799421b00a7950)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "54.36.166.103:11625",
            "id" : "GAGMH",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "v11.0.0"
         },
         {
            "address" : "18.140.91.137:11625",
            "id" : "GBAVU",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.1.0 (324c1bd61b0e9bada63e0d696d799421b00a7950)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "157.245.72.119:11625",
            "id" : "GBDU7",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.4.0 (38f51d60bd7aa473edea6038aaf13c255d79c14d)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "34.92.72.55:11625",
            "id" : "GCNDW",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.0.0 (de0b21c0ecc367b6883693bcbf53010941dcd5e6)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "18.207.213.63:11625",
            "id" : "sdf2",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.1.0~rc2 (8afe57913a08deffa247d7b5f837e0b28a54b864)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "152.32.170.134:11625",
            "id" : "GDXSR",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.0.0 (de0b21c0ecc367b6883693bcbf53010941dcd5e6)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "139.180.195.214:11625",
            "id" : "GD5MQ",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "v11.3.0rc1"
         }
      ]
   },
   "pending_peers" : {
      "inbound" : null,
      "outbound" : null
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'quorum'

```
2019-10-24T08:27:38.275 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:27:38.280 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 505
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:27:38.289 GB6R7 [default INFO] {
   "node" : "GD65K",
   "qset" : {
      "agree" : 3,
      "delayed" : null,
      "disagree" : null,
      "fail_at" : 2,
      "fail_with" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3" ],
      "hash" : "59d361",
      "ledger" : 1341481,
      "missing" : null,
      "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
      "value" : {
         "t" : 2,
         "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
      }
   },
   "transitive" : {
      "critical" : null,
      "intersection" : true,
      "last_check_ledger" : 1329406,
      "node_count" : 4
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'quorum?transitive=true'

```
2019-10-24T08:30:16.574 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:30:16.575 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1403
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:30:16.579 GCCHI [default INFO] {
   "critical" : null,
   "intersection" : true,
   "last_check_ledger" : 1329406,
   "node_count" : 4,
   "nodes" : [
      {
         "distance" : 0,
         "heard" : 1341508,
         "node" : "GD65K",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "tracking",
         "value" : "[ txH: 094e3b, ct: 1571905814, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 1
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341508,
         "node" : "sdf2",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "tracking",
         "value" : "[ txH: 094e3b, ct: 1571905814, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 1
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341508,
         "node" : "sdf3",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "tracking",
         "value" : "[ txH: 094e3b, ct: 1571905814, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 1
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341508,
         "node" : "sdf1",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "tracking",
         "value" : "[ txH: 094e3b, ct: 1571905814, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 1
      }
   ]
}
```

### Instance 2 data

- cat /opt/stellar/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-testnet1.stellar.org",
"core-testnet2.stellar.org",
"core-testnet3.stellar.org"]

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=XXX user=XXX password=XXX"
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1
CATCHUP_RECENT=8640

#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51 # rounded up -> 2 nodes out of 3
VALIDATORS=[
"GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
"GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
"GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]

[HISTORY.cache]
get="cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}"

#The history store of the Stellar testnet
[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

- stellar-core http-command 'info'

```
stellar-core http-command 'info'
2019-10-24T08:13:46.829 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:13:46.831 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1207
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:13:46.835 GCPYF [default INFO] {
   "info" : {
      "build" : "v11.3.0rc1",
      "history_failure_rate" : "0.25",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 836023,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 5000000,
         "closeTime" : 1571068803,
         "hash" : "e70b405e62cf125668422aa7a59bfcfc2910cfbba7d1eda9e1755567ba95712d",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 1187897,
         "version" : 11
      },
      "network" : "Test SDF Network ; September 2015",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 8,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 11,
      "quorum" : {
         "node" : "GBDSA",
         "qset" : {
            "agree" : 3,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 2,
            "hash" : "59d361",
            "ledger" : 1341329,
            "missing" : 0,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
         },
         "transitive" : {
            "critical" : null,
            "intersection" : true,
            "last_check_ledger" : 327531,
            "node_count" : 4
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2019-08-21T07:45:57Z",
      "state" : "Catching up",
      "status" : [ "Catching up: Running: catchup" ]
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'peers'

```
2019-10-24T08:23:51.683 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:23:51.685 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1730
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:23:51.688 GCOON [default INFO] {
   "authenticated_peers" : {
      "inbound" : null,
      "outbound" : [
         {
            "address" : "13.114.104.43:11625",
            "id" : "GAEPM",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.1.0 (324c1bd61b0e9bada63e0d696d799421b00a7950)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "18.140.91.137:11625",
            "id" : "GBAVU",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.1.0 (324c1bd61b0e9bada63e0d696d799421b00a7950)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "157.245.72.119:11625",
            "id" : "GBDU7",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 11.4.0 (38f51d60bd7aa473edea6038aaf13c255d79c14d)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "3.87.170.96:11625",
            "id" : "GCCM5",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.0.0 (de0b21c0ecc367b6883693bcbf53010941dcd5e6)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "3.218.204.21:11625",
            "id" : "GCUWV",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.0.0 (de0b21c0ecc367b6883693bcbf53010941dcd5e6)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "54.169.179.214:11625",
            "id" : "GDJ5P",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "v12.0.0"
         },
         {
            "address" : "152.32.170.134:11625",
            "id" : "GDXSR",
            "olver" : 10,
            "ver" : "stellar-core 12.0.0 (de0b21c0ecc367b6883693bcbf53010941dcd5e6)"
         },
         {
            "address" : "139.180.195.214:11625",
            "id" : "GD5MQ",
            "olver" : 9,
            "ver" : "v11.3.0rc1"
         }
      ]
   },
   "pending_peers" : {
      "inbound" : null,
      "outbound" : null
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'quorum'

```
2019-10-24T08:26:36.888 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:26:36.892 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 504
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:26:36.898 GBICN [default INFO] {
   "node" : "GBDSA",
   "qset" : {
      "agree" : 3,
      "delayed" : null,
      "disagree" : null,
      "fail_at" : 2,
      "fail_with" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3" ],
      "hash" : "59d361",
      "ledger" : 1341469,
      "missing" : null,
      "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
      "value" : {
         "t" : 2,
         "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
      }
   },
   "transitive" : {
      "critical" : null,
      "intersection" : true,
      "last_check_ledger" : 327531,
      "node_count" : 4
   }
}
```

- stellar-core http-command 'quorum?transitive=true'

```
2019-10-24T08:29:17.089 <startup> [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2019-10-24T08:29:17.091 <startup> [default INFO] Using QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
}

Content-Length: 1429
Content-Type: application/json

2019-10-24T08:29:17.095 GAR3A [default INFO] {
   "critical" : null,
   "intersection" : true,
   "last_check_ledger" : 327531,
   "node_count" : 4,
   "nodes" : [
      {
         "distance" : 0,
         "heard" : 1341497,
         "node" : "GBDSA",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "tracking",
         "value" : "[ txH: 17b978, ct: 1571905748, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 1
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341498,
         "node" : "sdf2",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "ahead",
         "value" : "[ SIGNED@sdf2 txH: 865dee, ct: 1571905756, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 2
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341498,
         "node" : "sdf3",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "ahead",
         "value" : "[ SIGNED@sdf3 txH: 865dee, ct: 1571905756, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 3
      },
      {
         "distance" : 1,
         "heard" : 1341498,
         "node" : "sdf1",
         "qset" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "sdf2", "sdf3", "sdf1" ]
         },
         "status" : "ahead",
         "value" : "[ SIGNED@sdf1 txH: 865dee, ct: 1571905756, upgrades: [ ] ]",
         "value_id" : 4
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you were (are still?) using a version of stellar-core not compatible with the network. `"build" : "v11.3.0rc1"` doesn’t support protocol 12 (network upgraded on Monday).

As of testnet, same thing (you need v12.1.0 or above), but you also need to rebuild it from scratch (`newdb`) as Testnet was just rebuilt yesterday.